# Laravel 5 and Angular Getting JSON From Controller

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json, laravel

This is more of a concept question, so I apologize if it isn't specific enough.

I am coming from a Jquery/AngularJS background; usually I am doing front-end stuff and only work with a back-end sparingly.

I am trying to learn Laravel 5 to expand my skills, but am having trouble conceptually fitting together what I know from Angular with what Laravel is telling me.

I want CRUD functionality to a database using Angular, but I want Laravel to help me get that database from MySQL to JSON so it can be passed.

What I have done is made the following in Laravel:

~Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pun extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */

     public $timestamps = false;
}
```

~Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Pun;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PunController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show a list of all available puns.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $puns = Pun::all();

        return Response::json($puns->toArray());
    }
}
}
```

~Route:

```
Route::get('showpunsfromdatabase', function () {
    return view('???');
});
```

The question marks above is where I am having trouble. If I understand it correctly, the controller is supposed to query the database as defined in the model, and output the results as JSON. How do I then direct Angular to this controller so I can get this JSON using the `$http` service? Does it have to go in a view that then pulls it in? I don't really want it in a "view", I just want the data (JSON) available to Angular. Am I thinking about this correctly?

My angular controller looks like this:

```
$scope.punGenerate = function(){
    $http.get("???").then(function (response) {$scope.thePunJSON = response.data;});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you do this:

```
Route::get('showpunsfromdatabase', function () {
    return view('???');
});
```

You are not calling the controller, you are returning the view directly. To call the controller your route should look like this:

```
Route::get('showpunsfromdatabase' ,  [
    'as' => 'showpunsfromdatabase.index',
    'uses' => 'PunController@index'
]);
```

Now, from the controller you should load the view including the info returned by the model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Pun;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PunController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show a list of all available puns.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $puns = Pun::all();

        return view('???')
           ->with(['puns' => json_encode($puns)]);
    }
}
```

It's just an example, because I don't know what are you looking for exactly.

Comment: Should the view in the controller that I am returning match the named route? `showpunsfromdatabase.index`?

Comment: Also sorry, where is `@index` coming from in the route?

Comment: No, is just an alias. For example if you create a FORM, you can do:

{!! Form::open(['route' => 'showpunsfromdatabase.index']) !!}

Comment: @index is the name of the action to be call in the controller. So it's like:

controller@action

Comment: So the view from the controller can just echo out the json for Angular, is this correct? Can you add what that view would look like in your answer?